# java web application destroy 1st login session after 2nd login

Tags: java, security, web

I am facing an issue handling multiple login to a java web application via multiple browser tabs. The scenario goes like this:

Steps:
1. User A login to application for the first time using user id "abc" via 1st browser tab
2. User A login to application for the second time using user id "cde" via 2nd browser tab
3. At this point, I am able to invalidate the session and redirect user back to login page.

HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
session.invalidate();

1. However, if User A performs the 3rd login using user id "cde"  via 2nd browser tab . He is still able to continue to execute transaction using 1st browser tab.

I would like to kick/prevent the user from carry on with any activities via the 1st browser tab. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Im not complete with you, but do you want to invalidate ALL sessions connected to the user A? Anyway, one way would be to use some sort of cache to store all active sessions for a user. And then when you invalidate one session you also invalidate ALL sessions for that user. You would also need to add check to check the session against this cache in approprtiate places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like browser Tab 1 is sending sessionId when you are attempting 3rd login. If you clear that sessionId from browser cookie then it will solve your problem.